# Binding variables as command parameter through binding expression

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

Is there any way to bind local varaibles and objects to command as command parameter.
If any one of the above is possible then please tell me.

Comment: You need to clear up what you're asking.  Providing the code you've tried would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean binding to a 'local variables', then its clearly not possible. You are setting up `DataContext` to some object, and then you can only bind to its properties or dependencyproperties, not local variables of some methods, which doesn't sound logical.

Comment: you can bind command to a property of a class, and then you can set that property value to your desired local variable, and then execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. Can you post some code?

You can do something like:

```
ICommand command = new ActionCommand(parameter => { this.CallFunction(parameter); });
```

Parameter is a type of object so you can pass any single object and then unbox it. Also ActionCommand requires Blend or at least the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assembly.

**UPDATED**

Ok in this case you are probaly best to define the ICommand on the view model and bind to it in XAML.

On the view model add an implementation like this:

```
public class AViewModel
{
    private ICommand _ACommand;

    public ICommand ACommand   
    {   
        get  
        {   
            if (this._ACommand == null)   
            {   
                this._ACommand = new ActionCommand(parameter =>   
                {   
                    // do stuff.
                });   
            }

            return(this._ACommand);   
        }   
    }

}
```

In XAML you need to bind to the data source which you have probaly already done.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:AViewModel x:Key="AViewModelDataSource" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AViewModelDataSource}}">
<TextBox x:Name="ABCTextBox" />
<Button x:Name="AButton" Command="{Binding ACommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ABCTextBox, Path=Text}" />
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to send property values in view to view model on button click through command parameter. In properties i set local variables so instead asking property values i asked for passing local variables.

Comment: @Ravi If the update doesn't work for you can you post some of your XAML and View Model class.